# How can I copy specify directories to a directory once?

Tags: linux, macos, shell

I want to copy specify directories(not all) to a directory once.

Don't want to execute the `cp -r` command line three times:

```
cp -r src/demo-2/containers/Loading src/demo-3/containers
cp -r src/demo-2/containers/NoMatch src/demo-3/containers
cp -r src/demo-2/containers/contact src/demo-3/containers
```

I try this command:

```
cp -r src/demo-2/containers/{Loading, NoMatch, contact} src/demo-3/containers
```

But it give me an error:

```
zsh: parse error near `}'
```

platform: OSX + zsh

Comment: Try this `cp -r src/demo-2/containers/Loading src/demo-2/containers/NoMatc src/demo-2/containers/contact src/demo-3/containers/`

Comment: Remove extra spaces: `cp -r src/demo-2/containers/{Loading,NoMatch,contact} src/demo-3/containers/`

Comment: @anubhava Thanks. it works. This is the best way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you just do `cp -r src/demo-2/containers/Loading src/demo-2/containers/NoMatch src/demo-2/containers/contact src/demo-3/containers/`

delimit them with spaces, give the target directory a forward slash.

Comment: Np, glad to hear it.